# Set of hashable custom elements inserts equal elements

Tags: swift, set, hashable

**Setup:**

I want to use a `Set` of the following `struct`:

```
struct NumberPair: Hashable {
    let n1: Int
    let n2: Int

    static func == (lhs: NumberPair, rhs: NumberPair) -> Bool {
        lhs.n1 == rhs.n1 && lhs.n2 == rhs.n2 ||
        lhs.n2 == rhs.n1 && lhs.n1 == rhs.n2
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(n1)
        hasher.combine(n2)
    }
}
```

I expected that inserting 2 elements that are equal (according to the function defined above) into an empty `Set` results in a `Set` with a single element:

```
    var pairs: Set<NumberPair> = []
//…
    pairs.insert(NumberPair(n1: 1, n2: 2))
    pairs.insert(NumberPair(n1: 2, n2: 1))
```

**Problem:**

However, at the 2nd insert I get an runtime error

```
Fatal error: Duplicate elements of type 'NumberPair' were found in a Set.
This usually means either that the type violates Hashable's requirements, or
that members of such a set were mutated after insertion.
```

When I set a breakpoint in the `static func ==`, this breakpoint is not hit.

**Question:**

Why is my custom equality function not called, and how to do it right?

Comment: It is a matter of taste, I find “tuple comparison” easier to read in the == method: `(lhs.n1, lhs.n2) == (rhs.n1, rhs.n2) || (lhs.n2, lhs.n1) == (rhs.n1, rhs.n2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `hash()` method violates the most important requirement of the [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol:

> Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order.

Example:

```
let p1 = NumberPair(n1: 1, n2: 2)
let p2 = NumberPair(n1: 2, n2: 1)

print(p1 == p2) // true
print(p1.hashValue) // -386759992433315259
print(p2.hashValue) // -5091661336101841357
```

Here `p1` and `p2` are “equal” but produce different hash values.

The hash method must be implemented in a way that it produces the same result if `n1` and `n2` are exchanged, for example

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(min(n1, n2))
    hasher.combine(max(n1, n2))
}
```

or

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(n1 ^ n2)
}
```

*Remark:* The second one is simpler and perhaps faster, but more likely to cause hash collisions. `struct Hasher` and its `combine(_:)` method where introduced in Swift 4.2 (among other reasons) in order to get rid of “XOR hashing,” see [SE-0206 SEHashable Enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md).